# How to specify argument type of object method by parent key

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to declare type of validation form rules

so, i have code like this:

```
type FormFields = {
  phone: number
  password: string
}

type ValidationRule = 'EMPTY' | 'MIN_LENGTH'

// some functions of validate
// const isPhoneLengthValid = (phone: number) => ...
// const isPhoneEmpty = (phone: number) => ...
// const isPasswordEmpty = (password: string) => ...

const formValidationRules: FormRules<FormFields, ValidationRule> = {
 phone: {
   EMPTY: (value) => isPhoneEmpty(value),
   MIN_LENGTH: (value) => isPhoneLengthValid(value)
 }
 password: {
  EMPTY: (value) => isPasswordEmpty(value)
 }
}
```

I need to write the FormRules generic type in such a way that it deduces the type of the validation method argument according to the key value from the FormFields passed to it

i tried this variant

```
type FormRules<FieldsT extends object, ValidationRulesT extends string>
  = Partial<Record<keyof FieldsT, Partial<Record<ValidationRulesT, (value: FieldsT[keyof FieldsT]) => boolean>>>>
```

but in this case typescript inferencing argument type in each method function without specifying type of value (for example like this `EMPTY: (value: string | number) => ...`)

but i need to specify it. If method is declared inside 'phone' parameter - the 'value' argument need to be 'number', not 'string' | 'number'. How to do that?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wR0pnm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with using `Record<keyof FieldsT, ⋯>` is that [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) doesn't allow you to associate particular keys in `K` with particular value types in `V`.  Instead you should write your own [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the properties of `FieldsT` so that each key has the right value type.

Here's one way to do it:

```
type FormRules<T extends object, R extends PropertyKey> =
    { [K in keyof T]: { [P in R]?: (value: T[K]) => boolean } }
```

So for each property key `K` in `keyof T`, `FormRules<T, R>` will have a property at key `K` whose value type is `{ [P in R]?: (value: T[K]) => boolean }`, equivalent to `Partial<Record<R, (value: T[K]) => boolean>>`; where `T[K]` is an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) representing the property type of `T` at key `K`.

Let's test it out:

```
type FormValidationRules = FormRules<FormFields, ValidationRule>;
/* type FormValidationRules = {
    phone: {
        EMPTY?: ((value: number) => boolean) | undefined;
        MIN_LENGTH?: ((value: number) => boolean) | undefined;
    };
    password: {
        EMPTY?: ((value: string) => boolean) | undefined;
        MIN_LENGTH?: ((value: string) => boolean) | undefined;
    };
} */
```

Looks good; the callback parameter type for `phone`'s properties is  `number`, while the callback parameter type for `password`'s properties is `string`, as expected.  And therefore

```
const formValidationRules: FormRules<FormFields, ValidationRule> = {
    phone: {
        EMPTY: (value) => isPhoneEmpty(value),
        MIN_LENGTH: (value) => isPhoneLengthValid(value)
    },
    password: {
        EMPTY: (value) => isPasswordEmpty(value)
    }
}
```

compiles with no error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwLYwJYQDYBMDOUC8UA3gFBTlRgAWcAdhAFxS0CuSARhAmRWAIY4cAd0RYmOYAlS0A5iQC+JEqEhQAanwyosfYKjoAlFhmiEA5AFEAsgAUAKgE0zUAD5QzVgJIA5APoAZC28AcTsACTMlAHooqBw4JGgAMxZaAGM9Ojw4JKgAN01tXQgSLAg0jD4EaDSs4ChUHBsaen8IWWAqDS0xKAAKajpGZjZOBABKAgA+KHY4OBM+WgBuUvLK6qha2gkGppaICyQwUCYBg6ZWDi5J-Bm5hYgl1bKKqpq6vZsBYVEjk5AZ34ghECF6Eikslu93mixWShU0HgyCMJhwAB47FAIAAPYDtXBQODsABW5WAABooAZsXiCXgbAg4JAEKAANIQEAzfA8chEKAAbTZDVoUAA1pyclA7ABdJj8gU2EXUmUAfjOBQwLGGdiFMuhs1hT1F8igimU4CRiCQ3SKmVoqIgeEIyKQjoxrrQmFwVNtOntjqmqyiACooIjYNa-bp9A7jE6CMReZQLkmKOmoNZ7A51f0+prtZdRjdpobHktJm5UmUktIIFhVhmKF4-IEQuFc3185pCyNrhNSw84ZWoNWILX6A3k-JG7wfqDeqQm+Qs45O92tcMIdIZAah8aR2OJ-XZ02WwEgqEwuuC1vJDu90aK65R7Qa3Wp+mZwooCGokoSG2XYkijQp-Vjd0mFdd10U9dBsBwX0wJjQx425NNeFTJdl1XBwNR7CADUaZohn+UAN21cYKWTdNzzbK98M3Ij9iGNoOi6MCKMI6dqPTYFfjBeUaIoXDGMo0tiPnP5jnI29xmnBQSCAA)